# How to inherit methods and then add something to them?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods

```
class uni_person {
    public:
    string f_name;   // 1
    string s_name;   // 2
    int age;         // 3
    string institute;// 5
    string uni;      // 6 
    string p_number; // 7

    void addSmth() {
        int x;
        cout << "What do you want to add about the student ?\n1: first name\n2: second name\n3: age\n4: course\n5: institute\n6: university\n7: phone number\n8: group\n";
        cin >> x;
        switch (x) {
            case 1: cin >> f_name; break;
            case 2: cin >> s_name; break;
            case 3: cin >> age; break;
            case 5: cin >> institute; break;
            case 6: cin >> uni; break;
            case 7: cin >> p_number; break;
            default: cout << "Error" << endl; break;
        }
    }
};

class Student: public uni_person {
    public:
    int course;
    int group;

    void addSmth() {
        int x;
        cout << "What do you want to add about the student ?\n1: first name\n2: second name\n3: age\n4: course\n5: institute\n6: university\n7: phone number\n8: group\n";
        cin >> x;
        switch (x) {
            case 4: cin >> course; break;
            case 8: cin >> group; break;
        }
    }
};
```

So I have a problem, I'm currently learning OOP in c++ and Ive came to this problem... How do to make class inherit other classes method and add something new to it without rewriting it? Is there a special function for it or what? 
I rewritten `addSmth()` and want to add some more behavior to addSmth().

Comment: The easiest way would be to add a call to `uni_person::addSmth()` to the `Student`s `addSmth()`.

Comment: You can't add to a switch case like that, closest you can get is to use an array of functions and index them with `x` instead of switching on it.

Comment: If you separate the input code into another funtion, you can call `uni_person::addSmth` from `Student::addSmth` if x is neither 4 nor 8.
Also, you should probably mark the `Student::addSmth()` function `override` and `uni_person::addSmth()` `virtual`

Comment: The best way is to move user interaction out of these classes completely.

Comment: Declare `addSmthh()` as a `virtual` function of `uni_person`.   Then override it in class `Student` (rather than, since it is currently not `virtual`, hiding it as you are).    From there, the implementation of `Student::addSmth()` can call `uni_person::addSmth()`.

Answer (score 0):

First you should separate the user interaction from the actual logic. If you have that you can call the Base function from the Derived function explicitly:

Also you should probably mark the base functions `virtual` and the derived functions `override`.

```
virtual void uni_person::promptAddSmth()
{
    cout << "What do you want to add about the student ?\n1: first name\n2: second name\n3: age\n4: course\n5: institute\n6: university\n7: phone number\n8: group\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    addSmth(x);
}

virtual void uni_person::addSmth(int x)
{
    switch (x) {
    case 1: cin >> f_name; break;
    case 2: cin >> s_name; break;
    case 3: cin >> age; break;
    case 5: cin >> institute; break;
    case 6: cin >> uni; break;
    case 7: cin >> p_number; break;
    default: cout << "Error" << endl; break;
    }
}

void Student::promptAddSmth() override
{
    cout << "What do you want to add about the student ?\n1: first name\n2: second name\n3: age\n4: course\n5: institute\n6: university\n7: phone number\n8: group\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    addSmth(x);
}

void Student::addSmth(int x) override
{
    switch(x) {
    case 4: cin >> course; break;
    case 8: cin >> group; break;
    default: uni_person::addSmth(x); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add some more behavior to a method which does not expect in in C++. But you can design your method for addition from the beginnig:

```
class uni_person
{
public:
    string f_name;   // 1
    string s_name;   // 2
    int age;         // 3
    string institute;// 5
    string uni;      // 6
    string p_number; // 7

    void addSmth()
    {
        int x;
        cout << "What do you want to add about the student ?\n1: first name\n2: second name\n3: age\n4: course\n5: institute\n6: university\n7: phone number\n8: group\n";
        cin >> x;
        switch (x) {
            case 1: cin >> f_name; break;
            case 2: cin >> s_name; break;
            case 3: cin >> age; break;
            case 5: cin >> institute; break;
            case 6: cin >> uni; break;
            case 7: cin >> p_number; break;
            default: cout << "Error" << endl; break;
        }

        // Call additional code. Does nothing by default.
        appendix();
    }

protected:

    virtual void appendix() {}
};

class Student: public uni_person
{
public:
    int course;
    int group;

private:
    void appendix() override
    {
        // Code from your Student::addSmth().
        // Will be called at the end of uni_person::addSmth().

        int x;
        cout << "What do you want to add about the student ?\n1: first name\n2: second name\n3: age\n4: course\n5: institute\n6: university\n7: phone number\n8: group\n";
        cin >> x;
        switch (x) {
            case 4:case 4: cin >> course; break;
            case 8: cin >> group; break;
        }
    }
};
```

Another child class might add some other behavior, which will be called correctly due to virtuality.

Also please mind other participants' advice about you design and code style.